# Remove item from AnimatedList- Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animatedlist

I was using [AnimatedList](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AnimatedList-class.html) in flutter for animating the items in the list. The animation is working properly when an item is added to the list. But when an item is removed, either an error comes (see below) or the wrong item is being animated: https://res.cloudinary.com/drcxef0qi/video/upload/v1645354884/5f5d2ff9-7e82-424a-96b5-ecf097a89316_bpojds.mp4

This error only comes when the item deleted is the last one in the list:
`RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0`

Here's the code I'm using:

```
void removeItem(String id) {
 int index = listofItems.indexWhere((e) => e['_id'] == id);

 listofItems.removeAt(index);
 _key.currentState!.removeItem(
    index, (_, animation) => listanim(animation, listofItems[index]),
    duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500));
 }
```

AnimatedList:

```
AnimatedList(
  shrinkWrap: true,
  itemBuilder: (_, int index, Animation<double> animation) => listanim(animation, listofItems[index]),
  initialItemCount: listofItems.length,
  key: _key,
)
```

Thank you!

Comment: hi can you provide your code for the AnimatedList

Comment: can u share me ur anydesk id

Comment: @AliNabel Thanks! I've updated the question with the code included

Answer (score 1):

this happen beacuse when you remove all items from the list
the animatedList will return error because there is no items

to fix that just add this to check if the items is empty or not

```
          listofItems.isNotEmpty?
      AnimatedList(itemBuilder: itemBuilder,initialItemCount: index,)
      : const CircularProgressIndicator(),
```

Comment: Thank you! But now the list items are not shown and this error comes: `Unhandled Exception: Null check operator used on a null value`. The animation issue still persists: https://seupload.com/472/5f5d2ff9-7e82-424a-96b5-ecf097a89316.mp4

Comment: hi @AjitKumar the idea is to check if the list have items then draw it on the screen an if its empty then return another widget 
you should take your list that have items and check for it 
i dont have the full code to decide what you should do 
so that you should do it your self with above concept 
and if you cant figure out how to do it 
please give me the full code of the screen

Comment: @AjitKumar Did this help you ?

Comment: I understood the concept...But if you see this video, you can see that during the animation the wrong item is being animated- https://res.cloudinary.com/drcxef0qi/video/upload/v1645354884/5f5d2ff9-7e82-424a-96b5-ecf097a89316_bpojds.mp4. That is the issue I'm facing